# ssh chroot to lxc container

Tags: linux, chroot, lxc

I have a PC with sshd service (192.168.1.1).
The PC contains two users user1 and user2.
I installed lxc service and configured a container.
How can I configure ssh server on 192.168.1.1 that connecting user2 will be chrooted to lxc container.

Comment: I doubt you can do this unless you're actually SSH'ing to the IP address of the container itself.

Comment: I have one dedicated static ip. Users must connect via ssh using that ip address. But every user must be chroot to its lxc container.

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSH may be configured to only allow a particular user to execute a particular command, by prepending a string to the public key in the `authorized_keys` file.

This:

```
ssh-rsa <key> <key name>
```

Should be changed to this

```
command="chroot command" ssh-rsa <key> <key name>
```

Comment: I want that user can't login without chroot into the server

Comment: That's what this does.

Comment: How can I connect over sftp to ssh of lxc container?